# Use hook_webform_submission_presave () to edit the SID of a Drupal webform

Tags: hooks, webforms, forms

I'm working with Drupal 7 and I've created a module called uvic. What I'm trying to do is to restart the SID when a form is cleared but it isn't working, what I'm doing wrong?

```
function uvic_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) { 

   $result = db_select('webform_submissions', 'sid') 
   ->fields('sid') 
   ->condition('nid', $node->nid) 
   ->orderBy('sid', DESC) 
   ->range(0,1) 
   ->execute(); 
   ->fetchAssoc(); 

if($submission->nid == $node->nid){
  if ($result) { 
    $submission->['sid'] = $result['sid'] + 1; 
  } else { 
   $submission->['sid'] = 1; 
  } 
} 

$component_id = 4; 
$submission->data[$component_id][0] = 'foo'; 

}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: PHP doesn't recognize `$submission->['sid']` as correct syntax. You are mixing access to an object method/property with array access; or you use one, or the other.